# LIS2DE12 accelerometer configurations

Tags: interrupts, accelerometer, high-pass-filter, configuration

I am working with LIS2DE12 accelerometer. Communicating with it via I2C. Retrieving simple data works fine, but now I want to configure it to generate interrupt on strong acceleration, but I'm a bit confused with configurations: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis2de12.pdf

I set ODR to 100 Hz, scale to 8g, OR combination of X high and low event interrupts, so as I understood, it will generate interrupt if one of the conditions was fulfilled, but there was also these configs for interrupt:
[image]

movement and orientation recognition. What are those known zones? As I understood, if movement option is set and I configure it to detect movement on X axis with for example g value of 16, it will generate interrupt every time my sensor moves in X axis with an acceleration of 16 g ? If this is the case then how to set that value? There is a register called Reference ( Reference value for interrupt generation. Default value: 0 ) so by sending some value to this register, I will set the threshold? Also what does The interrupt signal remains for a duration ODR? So if my ODR is 100 Hz, interrupt signal will be held high for 1/100 s ? Will it be High just once?

Another really big question is about filters, I am very confused or lack of knowledge in High pass filter of this sensor:
[image]

Why would I need high pass filter? Shouldn't Low pass filter help me to filter out noise and jitter and provide me with more averaged data? Why use high pass filter? And also how to configure it for my purpose? Why there are 2 normal modes, but one with reset function? What is reset function for a filter? What is reference signal used for filtering in this sensor and how to set it? I'm just unfamiliar with accelerometers internal filters and how to use them. Maybe the lack of documentation or explanation is the problem, because it seems like ST hopes that I know about all these functions and configs.